# Why is "step" argument necessary when predicting using data tensors? what does this error mean?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to `predict()` the output for a single data point `d`, using my trained Keras model loaded from a file. But I get a `ValueError If predicting from data tensors, you should specify the 'step' argument.` What does that mean?

I tried setting `step=1`, but then I get a different error `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor u'input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 600)'`.

Here is my code:

```
d = np.concatenate((hidden[p[i]], hidden[x[i]])).resize((1,600))
hidden[p[i]] = autoencoder.predict(d,steps=)
```

The model is expecting `(?,600)` as input. I have concatenated two `numpy` arrays of `shape (300,)` each to get `(600,)`, which is resized to `(1,600)`. This `(1,600)` is my input to `predict()`.

Comment: I figured out, the problem is with the resize function. It  makes 'd' as 'None' .

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the input to predict was `None` (because I had a bug in another part of the code).

Answer (score 1):

In official doc, steps refer to the total number of steps before stopping. So steps=1 means make predictions on one batch instead of making prediction on one record (single data point).

https://keras.io/models/sequential/

Comment: "steps: Total number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring the prediction round finished." So just set steps=1 by default? Why is it not the default?

Answer (score 1):

-> Define value of steps argument,

```
d = np.concatenate((hidden[p[i]], 
hidden[x[i]])).resize((1,600))
hidden[p[i]] = autoencoder.predict(d,steps=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a test data generator, it is good practice to define the steps, as mentioned in the documentation.

If you are predicting a single instance, no need to define the steps. Just make sure the argument (i.e. instance 'd') is not None, otherwise that error will show up. Some reshaping may also be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i got the same error, i just reshaped the data to predict with numpy function reshape() to the shape of the data originally used to train the model.