# ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a model with GradientTape in Keras. Here is the code:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(x,y):
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                
        predictions = model.predict(x)
        
        loss = compute_loss(y, predections)
    
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    
    return loss

history = []

for iter in tqdm(range(num_iters)):
    
    x_batch, y_batch = get_batch(x_train, y_train, batch_dim)
    loss = train_step(x_batch, y_batch)
    history.append(loss.numpy().mean())
```

This code leads to the following error:

```
ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model, you should specify the `steps` argument.
```

However if I try to call the prediction outside the function as follows:

```
history = []

for iter in tqdm(range(num_iters)):
    
    x_batch, y_batch = get_batch(x_train, y_train, batch_dim)       
    x_hat = model.predict(x_batch)
```

I get no error...

Can someone explain me why do I get this behavior from Keras?

Comment: could you print out the result of the `get_batch` function?

Comment: This previous discussion may help [Question-54547681](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547681/why-is-step-argument-necessary-when-predicting-using-data-tensors-what-does-t)

Comment: @tornikeo get_batch outputs two numpy arrays of shape (batch_size, 512, 512, 1)

Comment: @stephen_mugisha I already checked that answear before posting this one but I couldn't get rid of my problem...

Comment: @francesco in order to use `tf.function` you must specify input and output shapes and data types. That is likely causing problems. Does you error change if you remove the `tf.function` decorator?

Comment: @tornikeo what I did for make it work is the following: I changed the data type of `x_batch ` and `y_batch` to float32 and then called `model(x_batch)` for predicting the output. In this way everything worked fine (maintaining the `train_step` function as `@tf.function`)

Answer (score 1):

Answering here even though the user has answered in the comment for the benefit of the community.

By changing the data type of `x_batch`  and `y_batch` to `float32` and then called `model(x_batch)` for predicting the output.
In this way, the issue will be resolved and by maintaining the `train_step` function as `@tf.function`.